# How to update SwiftUI button after event in external class?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I want to update button, from "pause" sign, back to "play" sign; when the class finishes to do the speech task. Current code doesn't do any change... What's wrong?

Can I do `.onChange` with condition? (only if change is specific)

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    var speaker = Speaker()
    @State var isPlaying = false
        
    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                
                if isPlaying {
                    isPlaying.toggle()
                    speaker.synth.pauseSpeaking(at: .immediate)
                } else {
                    isPlaying.toggle()
                    // continue playing here if it was paused before, else ignite speech utterance
                    if speaker.synth.isPaused {
                        speaker.synth.continueSpeaking()
                    } else {
                        speaker.speak("Holly Molly bro")
                    }
                    
                }
            }, label: {
                Text(isPlaying ? "pause" : "play")
            })
            
            
        }
        .onChange(of: speaker.hasStopped, perform: { value in
            isPlaying = false
            print("Who asked for change?")
        })
        
    }
}
```

...

```
import AVFoundation
import Combine

class Speaker: ObservableObject, AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate {
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    
    @Published var hasStopped: Bool = false

    func speak(_ string: String) {
            hasStopped = false
            
            let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: string)
            utterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-GB")
            utterance.rate = 0.4
            synth.speak(utterance)
        }
    
    func speechSynthesizer(_ synthesizer: AVSpeechSynthesizer, didFinish utterance: AVSpeechUtterance) {
            print("all done")
            
            hasStopped = true
        }
}
```

Comment: Why don’t you check hasStopped directly instead of using a local @State property?

Comment: I thought about this, but don't remember why I changed my mind. Do you think to replace `isPlaying` into `class`, instead? I also toggle the states when pressing the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap `ObservableObject` property into `ObservedObject` wrapper, so published properties being tracked, like

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var speaker = Speaker()     // << here !!
    // @StateObject var speaker = Speaker()     // << if single per view !!
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Asperi's answer you also need to set the Delegate:

```
  override init() {
    super.init()
    synth.delegate = self 
  }
```